# java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.HashMap

Tags: java, netbeans

When I run my code I get a screen that asks for a reference(already coded and works perfectly). So when I input `IW1` for reference my output should be the details of `IW1` which is `"IW1", new troop(1, "Twisters", 200, 200))`. However I get with the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,OODCwk.troop>`

The `OODCwk`is the name of the package

```
public String getTroopDetails(String ref)
    {
        if ("IW1".equals(ref) ){
            HashMap<String, troop> Troop= getTroopDetails(ref);
            System.out.println(Troop.get("IW1"));
            
            
        }else{
            return "!";
        } 
        return "\nNo such troop";
    }

private void setupTroop()
    {
        HashMap<String, troop>Troop= new HashMap<String, troop>();
        
        Troop.put("IW1", new troop(1, "Twisters", 200, 200)); 
 
    }


public class troop{
    int FleetRef;
    String FullName;
    int ActivationFee;
    int BattleStrength; 
    
    public troop(int FRef, String FName, int AFee, int BStrength)
    {
        FleetRef = FRef;
        FullName = FName;
        ActivationFee = AFee;
        BattleStrength = BStrength;
    }
    
    public int getFleetRef()
    {
        return FleetRef;
    }
    public String getFullName()
    {
        return FullName;
    }
    public int getActivationFee()
    {
        return ActivationFee;
    }

    public int BattleStrength()
    {
        return BattleStrength;
    }
}
```

Comment: In "getTroopDetails()", I think you meant to call `setupTroop()`, not "getTroopDetails()"

Comment: @paulsm4 ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: OODCwk.SpaceTroops.setupTroop```  this is the error i get if i do that. ```SpaceTroops``` is a class that has the method ```setupTroop```

Comment: What for is recursive invocation `getTroopDetails` in the method `getTroopDetails`?  Method `setupTroop` declared as void but it returns the hashmap `Troop`.

Comment: @AlexRudenko the return value is useless indeed so i removed it

Comment: In method `setupTroop` a _local_ map is created and therefore it is lost when the method is done.  Method `getTroopDetails` is declared to return `String`, but there is a recursive call where String is assigned to the `HashMap` which cannot be compiled -- this is the error in your question.   Do you have a slightest idea which purpose of this code should be?

Comment: @AlexRudenko what i'm trying to achieve is that once I input ```IW1```, i want the output to be the details of ```IW1``` which is ```1, "Twisters", 200, 200``` and if any other input is detected it returns ```No such troop```

Comment: So you want a single method `getTroopDetails` to return results of different types `String` and `HashMap`  depending on the input.  This is not feasible in Java.

Comment: @AlexRudenko how should i go about this then? can you recommend me a way?

Answer (score 2):

There are several different problems here:

1. **Compile error**:

   `incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,OODCwk.troop>`

   SOLUTION: Don't call "String getTroopDetails()" if you need a Hashmap.
2. **Bogus call to getTroopDetails() inside method getTroopDetails()**

   SOLUTION: it sounds like you want to call a different method here.
3. **Class name "troop" should start with a capital letter**

SOLUTION: Per [Java naming conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/), you should rename your class `Troop`, and its constructor `public troop(int fRef, String fName, int aFee, int bStrength)`

4. **setupTroop() doesn't actually do anything**

SOLUTION: Move HashMap *OUT* of setupTroop() and make it a member of class "Troop".

Per your subsequent comments:

> @AlexRudenko what i'm trying to achieve is that once I input IW1, i
> want the output to be the details of IW1 which is 1, "Twisters", 200,
> 200 and if any other input is detected it returns No such troop

SOLUTION:

- Make HashMap<String, troop> a member variable.
- Give it a meaningful name, e.g. "troopDetails"
- Initialize the HashMap in your constructor
- Return the HashMap in getTroopDetails()

Comment: ```Make HashMap<String, troop> a member variable``` do you mean under class ```Troop``` so ```public class Troop{ HashMap<String, Troop> TroopDetails= new HashMap<String, Troop>();```

Comment: Yes. "troopDetails" (note the [camelcase](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/) capitalization for variable names) should be a member variable of class "Troop".  Similarly, getTroopDetails() and setupTroop() should be methods of class "Troop".