# Loading hashmap values in another method

Tags: java, netbeans

I've a method called `setupTroop` that stores the data through hashmap. How do I go about loading this data in `getTroopDetails`, so whenever the key has been called, its value gets loaded.

So if the key `IW1` gets called, the values `1, "Twisters", 200, 200` are outputted and if any other key gets called it gives the output `"No such troop"`.

```
private void setupTroop()
    {
        HashMap<String, troop>Troop= new HashMap<String, troop>();
        
        Troop.put("IW1", new troop(1, "Twisters", 200, 200)); 
 
    }
```

```
public String getForceDetails(String ref)
    {
        return "\nNo such force";
    }
```

```
public class troop{
    int FleetRef;
    String FullName;
    int ActivationFee;
    int BattleStrength; 
    
    public troop(int FRef, String FName, int AFee, int BStrength)
    {
        FleetRef = FRef;
        FullName = FName;
        ActivationFee = AFee;
        BattleStrength = BStrength;
    }
    
    public int getFleetRef()
    {
        return FleetRef;
    }
    public String getFullName()
    {
        return FullName;
    }
    public int getActivationFee()
    {
        return ActivationFee;
    }

    public int BattleStrength()
    {
        return BattleStrength;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70339505/java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-java-util-hashmap)

Comment: Please do not create duplicates of the same question.

Comment: HashMap<String, troop>Troop is a local variable.  You need to make it a global variable (make it an instance variable).

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to return a non string object on a String method. But there is a way of returning a troop if the `"IW1"` key is called.

The way of doing it is declaring the Troop HashMap outside of the setupTroop method, and then creating it inside the setupTroop method, like this:

```
HashMap<String, troop> Troop;

//Code you have
private void setupTroop() {
   Troop = new HashMap<String, troop>();
   Troop.put("IW1", new troop(1, "Twisters", 200, 200)); 
}
//Other code
public troop getForceDetails(String ref) {
   if(ref.equals("IW1") {
      return Troop.get(ref);
   }
   return null;
}
```

Then in whatever other method you have where you called the `getForceDetails()` method, you would have

```
if(getForceDetails("Some string") == null) {
   doSomething;
}
```

Comment: ```return Troop.get(ref);``` gives an error ```Troop cannot be converted to String```

Comment: @EngineerHus does the `getForceDetails` method start with `public String` or `public troop`? Since when you get the value from the HashMap, it's going to return a troop, not a String

Comment: i added my ```troop``` class code in the edit above

Comment: starts with ```public String```

Comment: @EngineerHus You have to change it to public troop, otherwise you'll be trying to return a `troop` when the method is supposed to return a `String`.

Comment: i need to keep it as ```public String```, is the a way for this?

Comment: @EngineerHus After seeing the edit you made to the post, since you have a `getFullName()` method in the `Troop` class, you can keep it as a String method and put `return troops.get(ref).getFullName();` and it will return a String

Comment: error gone, but new error arises, ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException```

Comment: When you call the `getForceDetails(ref)` are you calling it with a String that exists as a HashMap key? If it doesn't exist in the HashMap then it will throw a NullPointerException